# I am not getting the sum of the 2 numbes correct using the read and write in C?

Tags: c, integer

I am computing the sum of 2 numbers in the child process and printing it through the Parent process. But the sum is not coming correct?

```
int main()
{

    int a,b;
    printf("\nEnter the value of a = ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("\nEnter the value of b = ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    pid_t fork_return = fork();
    int fd1[2];
    pipe(fd1);

    if (fork_return==0)  //Child Process
    {
        printf("\nI am the child process\n");
        int sum;
        sum=a+b;
        // close the reading end of the fd1
        close(fd1[0]);
        write(fd1[1],&sum,sizeof(sum));
        close(fd1[1]);
    }
    else if(fork_return>0)
    {

        // close the writing end of the fd1
        close(fd1[1]);
        int sum_read;
        read(fd1[0],&sum_read,sizeof(sum_read));
        printf("\nParent Process\n");
        printf("\nsum of %d and %d is = %d\n",a,b,sum_read);
        close(fd1[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output of 2+3 to be 5, but the actual output is coming to be random 7-8 digits like 1438521280.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the pipe correctly. It's created after the fork, so you're just manipulating two unrelated pipes.

Comment: the OPs code, as posted, does not compile!   Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first call `pipe()`, only afterwards call `fork()`.

See more [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html).

Comment: Thank you nivpeled. I was doing this error only.  Now it's working correctly.